# How to decrypt this strange Base64 hash?

Tags: php, encryption, base64

I was trying to decrypt this hash but with no success. The hash is **Y_ZUP7l05osR3kg7T5jTYORC7CNeWA--** and it's BASE64

- '=' is replaced with '-'
- '+' is replaced with '.'
- '/' is replaced with '_'

So it's actually *Y/ZUP7l05osR3kg7T5jTYORC7CNeWA==* It prints out something strange **cöT?¹tæÞH;OÓ`äBì#^X** but the length of the strange output string coincide with the length of the input string.

Comment: __Note:__ encryption, hashes and encoding are all different things, which is it?

Comment: Is it a hash, or is it just base64 encoded text?  Two different things.  It decodes to 'cT?tH;O`B#^X' for  me as well.  Remember hashes are *not* reversible.

Comment: Maybe this is a `base64` representation of a binary encryption. Can you give us more info on how this hash is made?

Comment: it's a result of email address + salt(9 randomly created chars/numbers). but I am not sure if another method liker ROT13 or sth else was used. It could be a hash, but if the input email length is 10 chars + 9 chars for salt, and when I try to decode the output BASE64 the result is 19 chars (19-9=10 cahrs for the email).

Comment: This whole scheme reeks of adding complexity without adding security.

Answer (score 0):

As commenters have said, if it is a hash, you can't "decrypt" it, because it's not really encrypted, but hashed. Hashes are meant to be irreversible "one way" functions. If it's encrypted, you could decrypt it, but you need to know what algorithm it was encrypted with, as well as what key was used. If it really is a hash, you also need to know what hash function was used. You can't decrypt hashes but you can try to brute force guess which string produces the target hash. Base64 is just a character encoding used to more reliably transmit and manipulate the characters produced by the hashing or encryption algorithm.

Comment: Even if it's hashed it has be possible to get at least the hashed result, right? If the decrypted string length is equal to the length of the non-encrypted text, it means that the salt is not with a random length. As far as I see there are changes on the output BASE64 converted text, e.g. replacing some letters with others, without making changes the length itself.

Comment: It doesn't mean that the salt (if one was used) was of non-random length, because hash functions produce the same length output regardless of what you feed into them. Whether the salt is random or non-random, or whether one was used or not, doesn't change the length of the hash function's output.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm should be like,

Encode:

```
$EncodedString =  base64_encode( 'Your string' . 'Your hash');
```

Decode:

```
 $decodedString = base64_decode($EncodedString);

  Removal of hash - $decodedString
```